# OpenMM engine options in openpathsampling (OPS) python library

Tags: python, openpathsampling, openmm

### Context:

I'm new to OpenMM and transition path sampling (TPS). I tried to set up a two-state TPS with the `openpathsampling` python library using the flexible length one-way shooting move. I used the OpenMM engine with the following two options:

```
engine_options = {'n_steps_per_frame': 500, # timestep=2fs
                  'n_frames_max': 1000}
```

I'm following the [ops tutorial](https://github.com/openpathsampling/ops_tutorial/blob/main/1_tps_sampling_tutorial.ipynb). I set the integration timestep to be 2 fs in the integrator. As I set the number of integration steps per returned snapshot to be 500, I think the frame interval should be 1 ps.

From what I understand, the first option controls the elapsed time between returned frames, and the second one limits the length of returned trajectories. But it seems that I still get paths longer than 1 ns in the resulting ensemble:

[image: pathlengthdistribution]

### Question:

I'm a bit confused about how the `'n_frames_max'` works. Does ops not stop the integration and abort/reject the move if a new path exceeds this length limit?

### Code :

```
from openmm import app
import openmm as mm
import openmm.unit as unit
import openmmtools

import openpathsampling as ops
import openpathsampling.engines.openmm as ops_openmm


gro = app.GromacsGroFile(os.path.join(md_path, 'nvt.gro'))
top = app.GromacsTopFile(os.path.join(md_path, 'topol.top'), 
                         periodicBoxVectors=gro.getPeriodicBoxVectors(),
                         includeDir=path_to_gmx)
system = top.createSystem(nonbondedMethod=app.PME,
                          nonbondedCutoff=1.0*unit.nanometers,
                          constraints=app.HBonds, 
                          rigidWater=True,
                          ewaldErrorTolerance=0.0005)
integrator = openmmtools.integrators.VVVRIntegrator(
    temperature=340*unit.kelvin,
    collision_rate=1.0/unit.picoseconds,
    timestep=2.0*unit.femtoseconds)
integrator.setConstraintTolerance(0.00001)

openmm_properties = {'DeviceIndex':'2'}
platform = mm.openmm.Platform.getPlatformByName('CUDA')
engine_options = {'n_frames_max': 1000,
                  'n_steps_per_frame': 500}
ops_topology = ops_openmm.tools.topology_from_pdb(os.path.join(md_path, 'nvt.gro'))
engine = ops_openmm.Engine(
    topology=ops_topology, 
    system=system, 
    integrator=integrator, 
    openmm_properties=openmm_properties,
    options=engine_options
).named('CLN_Openmm_engine')
engine.initialize(platform)
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with OpenMM, but it may help to see your whole input. Just to clarify, how do you know a frame is equivalent to 1ps (which seems to be what you are assuming when you say that setting the max number of frames equal to 1000 will limit the time length to 1000ps)]? Do you set the frame size or is it adjusted throughout the integration?

Comment: Please add the input files: `nvt.gro` and `topol.top` files as a code blocks.

Comment: The `nvt.gro` and `topol.top` are the gromacs format coordinate and topology files. They describe a protein in water system that include over six thousand atoms -- more than the character limit.

Comment: In that case please follow this link to add the files to the Github repo of MMSE and add the link to the file in the question. [Instructions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/why-do-we-not-allow-links-to-google-drive-files)

Comment: @Kui Were you able to upload the files to the Github repo?